# Unable to start VNC server because :0 is taken

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS. After install VNC I've tried to start the server and return this:

```
 ~ $ vncserver :0

Warning: raspberrypi:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X0-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server raspberrypi:0
A VNC server is already running as :0
```

If I remove that temp file, return this:

```
~ $ vncserver :0

Warning: raspberrypi:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
Remove this file if there is no X server raspberrypi:0
A VNC server is already running as :0
```

If I remove again, the server start, but a plain grey screen is shown trough VNC client. In short, after:

```
~ $ sudo rm /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
~ $ sudo rm /tmp/.X0-lock
~ $ vncserver :0

New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:0

Starting applications specified in /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:0.log
```

I can see this in the RealVNC client (screen capture):

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/40182G3E332b3f1j3846/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202013-11-11%20a%20las%2023.03.46.png?v=6719a796

I have no idea what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I've dicovered that I can run VNC in port :1

```
vncserver :1
```

then, I must connect VNC viewer at

```
myIP:1
```

It works.

Comment: VNC will usually run at :1 which is a different session. To run at :0, use x11vnc.

Comment: had same issue recently, i made VNC run on start up, but seems causes this issue. thx

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: TigerVNC can do the scrapping of X display
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-start-a-vnc-server-for-the-actual-display-scraping-with-tigervnc/

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue.

The default preferences are for "Auto Login" "Login as user Pi"
This means that the :0 session is already taken.

Un-click this option using Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration and your original scheme should work.

You can modify the default settings via the command line using

> sudo raspi-config

( options 3 -> B2 ) or via a new vnc session

or via a new vnc session using session :1
vncserver :1 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -dpi 96

Comment: You also need to disable "Boot to Desktop"

Answer (score 1):

You should use x11vnc, install it by `apt install x11vnc` and run
`x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:0 -display :0 -geometry 1280x720` to bind to the current X11 session.

After that, you can run `vncviewer <your-machine-name>:0` to connect to it. (You also need to install vncviewer, there are a few choices from `apt-cache search vncviewer`)

`vncserver` is inferior to `x11vnc` because it cannot bind existing X11 sessions, but can only create new X11 sessions. `x11vnc` can do both.

To eliminate the security starting message, you can set a password with `x11vnc -storepasswd` and run it with `x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:0 -display :0 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd`

Comment: This is the proper answer. To eliminate the huge security starting message, you can set a password with `x11vnc -storepasswd` and run it with `x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:0 -display :0 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill process that uses 5900 port (that mean :0). you can find that process like this - netstat -antup | grep 5900. Killing with kill -9 PID command. After that just start vncserver another time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but nothin returns with

sudo netstat -antup | grep 5900